# how to write json stream in core java

Tags: java, json

Need to send JSON data like below,

i.e Expected output:

```
[{"id","id1","desc" : "desc1", "val" :{"id","id1", "name":"name1"}]
```

So, I have written the java code as:

```
JSONStream json = new JSONStream();
{
    JSONStream jsonQuote = json.object();
    jsonQuote.value("id", "id1");
    jsonQuote.value("desc", "desc1");

    jsonQuote.list("val");
    {
        JSONStream jsonItem = jsonQuote.object();
        jsonItem.value("id", "id1");
        jsonItem.value("name", "name1");
        jsonItem.endobject();
    }
    jsonQuote.endlist();
    jsonQuote.endobject();
}
```

But the output is:

```
[{"id","id1","desc" : "desc1", "val" :[{"id","id1", "name":"name1"}]]
```

so I have to remove the `[` in the above code

Comment: Using a json library makes easier. `GSON`

Comment: the problem is certainly from the `jsonQuote.list("val")` call. You should probably do something like `jsonQuote.value("val", jsonItem)`

Comment: The above is not legal JSON.  Go to json.org to learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao -- He is using a JSON library.  Just not correctly.  (And streaming JSON is very difficult to use correctly, so he would indeed be well-advised to choose a different kit.)

Comment: see [Optimized way of writing/reading json file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73702885/4681265)

Answer (score 0):

First thing, the output you are looking for is invalid JSON - check it on [http://jsonlint.com/](http://www.JSONLint.com)

So assuming you want -

`[{"val":{"id":"id1","name":"name1"},"id":"id1","desc":"desc1"}]`

Code for this output using `JSON-Simple` library  -

```
   import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
   import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

   public class JSONTest 
   {


   public static void main(String[] args)  
   {
    JSONObject obj1=new JSONObject();
    obj1.put("id", "id1");
    obj1.put("desc", "desc1");

    JSONObject obj2=new JSONObject();
    obj2.put("id", "id1");
    obj2.put("name", "name1");

    obj1.put("val", obj2);

    JSONArray arr=new JSONArray();
    arr.add(obj1);

    System.out.println(arr);

}

}
```

Output-

```
  [{"val":{"id":"id1","name":"name1"},"id":"id1","desc":"desc1"}]
```

Comment: I'm new to java, please edit the code what i have given.

Comment: That's not how this works.  You ask a question and get an answer; it is your responsibility to integrate the answer with your project.