# Optimized way of writing/reading json file

Tags: java, json

So i have large JSON files (which contain a list of JSON object) and i have to:

- add/remove objects from the file's list of JSON objects
- update object's values (specifically this objects can have list of objects and i might have to add or remove elements from this list)
- read each object in the file (here i would like to load only the file for each object so that i don't have to load the whole file in the RAM keep in mind that this files are very heavy)

Here you can find an example of the file:

```
[

{
     "id":"1",
     "list":[
         { "id": "1", "example": "example" }, { "id": "2", "example": "example" }
     ]
},
{
     "id":"2",
     "list":[
         { "id": "1", "example": "example" }, { "id": "2", "example": "example" }
     ]
},
{
     "id":"3",
     "list":[
         { "id": "1", "example": "example" }, { "id": "2", "example": "example" }
     ]
},
...
]
```

For the part of updating the array i have tought of reading the object then change the array and replace the entire object in the file (it may work but i am open to better solutions).

How can i do this? (I am using Java)

Ok so currently i found a way of writing in the JSON file but not appending data to it (this is what i need) here is my code:

```
public void create(JSONObject document){
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(collectionPath));
            JSONWriter jsonWriter = new JSONWriter(fw);
            jsonWriter.object();
            Iterator<String> keys = document.keys();
            while(keys.hasNext()){
                String key = keys.next();
                jsonWriter.key(key);
                jsonWriter.value(document.get(key));
            }
            jsonWriter.endObject();
            fw.flush();
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

By doing this i write the file and i need to append the data not to write it (cause this replaces the already written data with the new data and i don't want this).

This is an example of the file keep in mind that this is an example and the real one could weight event gigabytes.

```
{"uid":"1","password":["keyboardcat","keyboardcat1"],"nestedObject":{"bool":true,"string":"stringa","int":1,"object":{"bool":true,"string":"stringa","int":1}},"username":"test"}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to look at https://github.com/anatolygudkov/green-jelly That's an example of stream/event-oriented parsing/generating of JSON. You can read a file part by part (with a byte buffer, for example) and pass to the parser and  produce a new JSON with the generator at the same time. See, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298341/java-edit-existing-json-file/59183538#59183538 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61868825/split-a-large-json-file-into-smaller-json-files-using-java/61918904#61918904 Jackson and Gson also support such streaming parsing/generating, BTW

Comment: Uhmm ok i have taken a look and it seems great! but what i don't understand is that when i update the json file does it read it entirely and rewrite it or does it something different? cause reading the entire file and rewrite it could be heavy and i would like to avoid that if possible

Comment: Formally speaking, you don't update your original file, you prepare a new one step by step/object by object/array item by item during the parsing of the original one. Or even to create a number of result files while parsing of one single file. The idea is to collect with callbacks and store as minimal info as possible. For example, to store all properties of one single object before writing it out by the generator. If you provide specific sample for both input and output files, I can be more specific with my answer as well :)

Comment: Ok so i found a solution to write (but not append) data in the JSON file i will update the answer with an example of the file, keep in mind that the file can even be of gigabytes of weight also thank you!

Comment: If you have GB files, then you shouldn't be using files. Use a proper database, even if that is SQLite

Comment: @OneCricketeer This is a data analysis project, we have to manipulate json files (without uploading them into a database) and we also have to use java to make the program platform independent.

Comment: @AndreaDattero OK, then this doesn't seem to be just an exercise how to manipulate the JSON data. And your data seems to be quite large. Also, typically, "data analysis" means that data is mostly being queried rather than written and a user may build any request and DB may don't have appropriate index built. As result, a "data analysis" system require specific storage like Vertica. There is a freeware and quite good alternative - https://clickhouse.tech/ Why wouldn't put your data from JSON to Clickhouse?

Comment: I didn't specify this (i didn't thought this was important), this is a university exercise, we have to do what our professor says unfortunately... They said that the size of the files they will use to test this exercise will reach the megabytes and the last one will be of 1 gigabyte.

Comment: You could use a tool like Apache Spark or Apache Hive, which are Java-based to manipulate and analyize JSON. Short answer is that there is no "optimized way" to write/read any JSON record because it depends on your query patterns. For example, look at JSONPath libraries.

Comment: Perfect i will check them out thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On the jackson-core site, at [Usage, simple reading chapter](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core#usage-simple-reading), the [Reading and Writing Event Streams](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/01/entry_132.html) example is provided where one can see how to read a large json file efficiently. You'll basically read the array items one by one, change them if you need to and then write them to a new file; if you need to remove some items you'll simply omit writing them while when you have to insert new items you'll simply write them after reading&writing (aka copying) the appropriate number of items from the original file. In the end you can replace the original file with the new one.

Below is an example of writing a large array of objects (`HashMap` here but could be any other) with `writePOJOField` method. I use *jackson-core* and *jackson-databind* (see https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

```
// given
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
JsonFactory jfactory = new JsonFactory(new ObjectMapper());
JsonGenerator jGenerator = jfactory.createGenerator(stream, JsonEncoding.UTF8);

// when
jGenerator.writeStartObject();
jGenerator.writeStringField("name", "Tom");
jGenerator.writeNumberField("age", 25);

jGenerator.writeFieldName("objects");
jGenerator.writeStartArray();
IntStream.range(0, 3).forEach(it -> {
    try {
        jGenerator.writePOJO(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
            put("key1", "value1");
            put("key2", "value2");
        }});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
});
jGenerator.writeEndArray();

jGenerator.writeFieldName("strings");
jGenerator.writeStartArray();
jGenerator.writeString("textX");
jGenerator.writeString("textY");
IntStream.range(0, 3).forEach(it -> {
    try {
        jGenerator.writeString("text-" + it);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
});
jGenerator.writeEndArray();

jGenerator.writeNullField("nullField");
jGenerator.writeEndObject();
jGenerator.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If You use `org.json.JSONObject` then try this `org.json.JSONTokener`

for read :

```html
public static JSONObject getJSONFromFile(String path){
        JSONObject result ;
        Path resultPath = Paths.get(path);
        try {
            InputStream stream = Files.newInputStream(resultPath);
            result = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(stream));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

for write :

```html
public static void writeJSON(JSONObject json, String path){
        Path filePath = Paths.get(path);
        if(Files.exists(filePath))
        {
            try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filePath.toFile())){
                writer.write(json.toString(4));
                writer.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you re-throwing a new, different exception? If you're not going to handle the exception, let the caller do it.